# jQuery validate max value on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to validate a form, when it gets submitted. I need to check the following things:

1. Whether the user has selected any option from the dropdown.
2. Whether the user has entered a value larger than the max-value

If any of this conditions is not matched, I want to show an error message in a modal window...

How can I achieve this behaviour? Below is a code snippet:

```js
//This function sets max value, based on selected option's data-max
$('select').change(function(e) {
  var selectedIndex = $('select').prop("selectedIndex");
  var selectedOption = $('select').find("option")[selectedIndex];
  $('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(selectedOption).data('max'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="./cart_update.php">
  Select Size:
  <select size="1" name="options" class="selectsize">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="30" data-max="50">30</option>
    <option value="31" data-max="50">31</option>
    <option value="32" data-max="40">32</option>
    <option value="33" data-max="50">33</option>
    <option value="34" data-max="50">34</option>
  </select>
  Quantity
  <input type="number" class="cart_qty" name="product_qty" size="1" value="1" min="1" max="100" />
  <button class="orange medium full add-to-cart" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

*As you didn't give any information on whether you validate the form data within the backend as well, I assume that you don't.*

1. Validating form data only on the client side (i.e. within the client's webbrowser) is **not** advisable. That is because clients can easily manipulate the javascripte code you're using to validate data. By doing so, it **is possible** to import fraudulent data into your application (and many many more bad things could happen).
2. Validating data on the client side should only be used *to give your users a quick feedback* on whether the entered information is correct and in accordance to your definitions. Real data validation, **before** you further use it within your application (i.e. store it within a database, or what ever), should happen on the server side.

I advise you reading these articles to further deep dive into the topic of data validation:

1. [Data form validation (mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)
2. If you're using *PHP* as a server-side language: [PHP 5 Form Validation (w3schools.com)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) or if you're using javascript *as a server-side* language: [How to Easily Validate Any Form Ever Using AngularJS(thecodebabarian.com)](https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/how-to-easily-validate-any-form-ever-using-angularjs/)
3. [Web Form Validation: Best Practices and Tutorials (smashingmagazine.com)](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/)

Coming to your question (and assuming you read the articles and now want to validate the data only for the user's sake), here's kind of a commented working code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Whenever your form is submitted, execute this function
    $('#ourForm').submit(function (e) {
        // Prevent the browser from executing the default behaviour -> submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // Now check the user's entered information for accordance to your definitions
        // #1: Check whether any checkbox is ticked
        var checkBoxValue = $('#ourCheckbox').val();
        // If checkBoxValue is undefined, there is no checkbox selected,
        if (!checkBoxValue) {
            // There is no checkBox ticked, throw error
            alert('Please select a checkbox!');
            return false;
        }
        // #2: Check whether entered value is smaller than the data-max field of the selected checkbox
        // Receive the user's entered value
        var enteredValue = $('#ourInputfield').val();
        // Receive the max value specified by you from the data-max field
        var maxValue = $('#ourCheckbox option:selected').attr('data-max');
        // If the entered value is bigger than the max-data value
        if (enteredValue > maxValue) {
            // The entered value is bigger than the data-max field of the selected checkbox, throw error
            alert('Your entered value is to large, please choose a value lower than ' + checkBoxValue.value);
            return false;
        }
        // Validating your form data is finsihed, go on with the real work
        alert('Your data looks fine, whoooo!');
    });
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77v1z18v/1/

Comment: I don't know why you assume there's no validation on the sever side, especially so strenuously. There's no mention of back-end at all, and it seems like a massive presumption to give PHP-related articles. The answer would be improved if you omit all of that and focus on the problem statement at hand.

Comment: Reading the question I had the impression that there is no data validation done on the server side. This might be true or false, but as the author gave no more information, I felt like mentioning it would be a good thing. The assumption of using PHP is based on the *cart_update.php* file the form is submitting to.